# bash: if statement works one way, but not with added process

Tags: bash, if-statement, xterm

This command works as expected.

```
if [[ "$fsb" > "19" || "$fsb" < "06" ]]; then
  xterm -name Xtermc
else
  xterm -name Xtermd
fi
```

But this does not, neither xterm is produced, let alone running the script (x0 or x100) within it.

```
if [[ "$fsb" > "19" || "$fsb" < "06" ]]; then
  xterm -name Xtermc -e x0
else
  xterm -name Xtermd -e x100
fi
```

Could someone kindly explain why?

Comment: does xterm support a `-e` parameter?

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely because `x0` and `x100` can't be found or exit immediately. Run

```
xterm -name Xtermc -e 'x0; read'
```

to see any error messages produced. If the command works fine, but finishes and exits immediately, you can get a prompt afterwards with

```
xterm -name Xtermc -e 'x0; bash'
```

Comment: Behavior is as you predicted, "can't be found", but both scripts exist in my .bashrc, and execute normally if invoked directly

Comment: `-e` requires an actual executable, not a shell function, which is what `x0` and `x100` appear to be when you say they "exist in [your] `.bashrc`".